# polars rolling by option not allowed?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a data frame of the type:

```
df = pl.LazyFrame({"day": [1,2,4,5,2,3,5,6], 'type': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'], "value": [1, 0, 3, 4, 2, 2, 0, 1]})


day type    value
i64 str i64
1   "a" 1
2   "a" 0
4   "a" 3
5   "a" 4
2   "b" 2
3   "b" 2
5   "b" 0
6   "b" 1
```

I am trying to create a rolling sum variable, summing, for each different "type", the values in a two days window. Ideally, the resulting dataset would be the following:

| day | type | value | rolling_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | a | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | a | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | a | 4 | 7 |
| 2 | b | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | b | 2 | 4 |
| 5 | b | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | b | 1 | 1 |

I tried using the following code:

```
df = df.with_columns(pl.col("value")
                     .rolling(index_column="day", by="type", period="2i")
                     .sum().alias("rolling_sum"))
```

but I get the error: "TypeError: rolling() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by'".

Could you help me fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because in your code you're trying to use [`Expr.rolling()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rolling.html) which doesn't have `by` parameter (strangely, it is mentioned in the documentation under `check_sorted` parameter - is it just not implemented yet?), instead of [`DataFrame.rolling()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.rolling.html).

If you'd restructure the code to use the latter then it works fine:

```py
(
    df.rolling(
        index_column="day", by="type", period="2i"
    )
    .agg(
        pl.col('value').sum().alias("rolling_sum")
    )
)

┌──────┬─────┬─────────────┐
│ type ┆ day ┆ rolling_sum │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---         │
│ str  ┆ i64 ┆ i64         │
╞══════╪═════╪═════════════╡
│ a    ┆ 1   ┆ 1           │
│ a    ┆ 2   ┆ 1           │
│ a    ┆ 4   ┆ 3           │
│ a    ┆ 5   ┆ 7           │
│ b    ┆ 2   ┆ 2           │
│ b    ┆ 3   ┆ 4           │
│ b    ┆ 5   ┆ 0           │
│ b    ┆ 6   ┆ 1           │
└──────┴─────┴─────────────┘
```

If you need to have `value` column in your result, you can use [`Expr.rolling_sum()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rolling_sum.html) combined with [`Expr.over()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.over.html) instead (assuming your DataFrame is sorted by `day` already):

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("value")
    .rolling_sum(window_size=2,min_periods=0)
    .over("type")
    .alias('rolling_sum')
)

┌─────┬──────┬───────┬─────────────┐
│ day ┆ type ┆ value ┆ rolling_sum │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---         │
│ i64 ┆ str  ┆ i64   ┆ i64         │
╞═════╪══════╪═══════╪═════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ a    ┆ 1     ┆ 1           │
│ 2   ┆ a    ┆ 0     ┆ 1           │
│ 4   ┆ a    ┆ 3     ┆ 3           │
│ 5   ┆ a    ┆ 4     ┆ 7           │
│ 2   ┆ b    ┆ 2     ┆ 2           │
│ 3   ┆ b    ┆ 2     ┆ 4           │
│ 5   ┆ b    ┆ 0     ┆ 2           │
│ 6   ┆ b    ┆ 1     ┆ 1           │
└─────┴──────┴───────┴─────────────┘
```

Ideally, I would probably expect `Expr.rolling` together with `Expr.over` to work:

```py
# something like this
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("value")
    .rolling(index_column="day", period="2i")
    .sum()
    .over("type")
    .alias('rolling_sum')
)

# or this
df.set_sorted(['type','day']).with_columns(
    pl.col("value")
    .sum()
    .over('type')
    .rolling(index_column="day", period="2i")
    .alias('rolling_sum')
)
```

but unfortunately, it doesn't:

```
InvalidOperationError: rolling expression not allowed in aggregation
```

**Update**

Using `rolling_sum()` might not be something you want, if you plan your window to be based on days / weeks etc.
In this case you can still use `DataFrame.rolling()` and combine it with [`Expr.last()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.last.html) inside of [`GroupBy.agg()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.dataframe.group_by.GroupBy.agg.html) to get the last value in the window:

```py
(
    df.rolling(
        index_column="day", by="type", period="2i"
    )
    .agg(
        pl.col('value').last(),
        pl.col('value').sum().alias("rolling_sum")
    )
)

┌──────┬─────┬───────┬─────────────┐
│ type ┆ day ┆ value ┆ rolling_sum │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---         │
│ str  ┆ i64 ┆ i64   ┆ i64         │
╞══════╪═════╪═══════╪═════════════╡
│ a    ┆ 1   ┆ 1     ┆ 1           │
│ a    ┆ 2   ┆ 0     ┆ 1           │
│ a    ┆ 4   ┆ 3     ┆ 3           │
│ a    ┆ 5   ┆ 4     ┆ 7           │
│ b    ┆ 2   ┆ 2     ┆ 2           │
│ b    ┆ 3   ┆ 2     ┆ 4           │
│ b    ┆ 5   ┆ 0     ┆ 0           │
│ b    ┆ 6   ┆ 1     ┆ 1           │
└──────┴─────┴───────┴─────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Roman!
The first method works well but, as you said, I would like to keep other columns as well. The rolling_sum method looked promising and it is what I wanted to use at first, however, the command you used creates a fixed rolling window of 2 observations, no matter the distance in terms of "day". When I try using the index count time delta '(window_size="2i", by="day")' it gives the error: InvalidOperationError: in `rolling_sum` operation, `by` argument of dtype `i64` is not supported (expected `date/datetime`). I tried casting day as a pl.Date, but it gives the same error

Comment: @Vincenzoalfano it wasn't clear from your example that you want to group within 2 days, 2i is `2 index counts`. See updated answer with using `rolling()` while keeping `value` column in a result.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion! Thank you, the updated part is exactly what I needed